# Solve $|1 + x| < 1$

Tags: absolute-value

I'm trying to solve $|1 + x| < 1$. The answer should be $ -2 < x < 0$ which wolframalpha.com agrees with.

My approach is to devide the equation to:
$1+x < 1$ and $1-x < 1$ and then solve those two:

$ 1+x < 1 $

$ x < 0 $

$ 1 - x < 1$

$ -x < 0$

$x > 0$

And this gives me $ x = 0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $1-x<1$ should be replaced by $-1-x<1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:
$$
|a|=
\begin{cases}
\;\;\;a &\text{if} \quad a\geq 0,\\
-a &\text{if} \quad a< 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence,
$$
|x+1|=
\begin{cases}
\;\;\;x+1 &\text{if} \quad x\geq -1,\\
-x-1 &\text{if} \quad x< -1.
\end{cases}
$$

- If $x+1\geq 0$ (or $x\geq -1$) then $|1+x|<1$ is equivalent to $1+x<1$ or $x<0$. Then in this case $-1\leq x<0$.
- If $x+1<0$ (or $x< -1$) then $|1+x|<1$ is equivalent to $-1-x<1$ or $x>-2$. Then in this case $-2<x<-1$.

In both cases we have $-2<x<0$.

Answer (score 3):

You have $1-x<1$, which is incorrect. It should be $1+x>-1$ instead. This gives us $x>-2$.

Answer (score 3):

Every exercise dealing with $| \cdot |$ can be solved as follows:

\begin{align}|1+&x| < 1 \\
(\iff) -1 < 1&+x < 1 \\
(\iff) -2 < &x < 0
\end{align}

Comment: If you had the inequality $|1 + x| > 1$, you would have $1 + x > 1$ or $1 + x < -1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It's the same as the negation of $|1+x|\leqslant 1$, the method still can be applied. Ok, "every exercise" is perhaps an exaggeration haha, but I think the general idea is always something like that.

Answer (score 3):

$|x-(-1)|<1$ says the distance between $x$ and $-1$ needs to be less than $1$. So $x$ is in $(-2,0)$. With practice, you can do these kinds of problems without step-by-step algebra.